# Passing variables with post to another page in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

My application is in asp.net 4.0, I want to redirect page to another page using jQuery and want to pass some variables using post method which should only be accessible on another page using form.request or it should not be visible in query string. I don't want to use session or application object for this?

Following is the code which I am using but it does not work.

```
$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_testid").val(val);
$('#form1').attr('method', 'post');
$('#form1').attr('action','Test.aspx');
$('#form1').find('#__VIEWSTATE').attr('name', '__VIEWSTATE');
window.location.href = 'Test.aspx';
return false;
```

or also i tried using

```
    $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_testid").val(val);
    document.forms['form1'].method = "post";
    document.forms['form1'].action = 'Test.aspx'
    document.forms['form1'].__VIEWSTATE.name = 'NOVIEWSTATE';
    document.forms['form1'].submit();
```

but it gives me error as

Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be going to Test.aspx without submitting anything...

Try with

```
$('#form1').submit()
```

instead of window.location...

Comment: Maybe your <form> tag does not have the correct values in the action and method attributes?

Comment: if the form tag has runat="server" then the html id is not #form1. Try $("#<%=form1.ClientID%>").submit()

Comment: using this $('#form1').submit() i can redirect but i need variable to accessible on other page.

Answer (score 0):

the `window.location.href` is not make postback !

Use the [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) from jQuery

`$('#form1').submit();`

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
$('#form1').submit();
```

in place of window.location.href

Comment: i tried using $('#form1').submit() but no luck. and i want pass variable so that it  will only be accessible using Form.Request[""]